# HTML page unload is not getting called always in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, onunload

I have an onunload method written on the body of a form. Since the page got large amount contents to be streamed from the server,it takes a while to download the entire form. While the form gets downloaded to the browser,if the user clicks the window close button, the unload event (written to call a server side action to reset some flag) is not getting triggered sometimes. The unload method is written towards the end of the page, is that a reason for this? Is there anyway by which we can make sure that onunload is guaranteed to be called?

Comment: From my past experience, the onunload event is not GUARANTEED to run as long as you might want it to. If the next page loads before your code finishes, it might not ever finish. Depending on the application, you can do an alert or a confirm prompt to give your code some time to execute.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that hits you is probably the fact that IE doesn't fire an unload event if window.onload hasn't fired yet. The solution is described in this blog post: http://blog.moxiecode.com/2008/04/08/unload-event-never-fires-in-ie/

Comment: Note: the onstop event described in that blog post doesn't work the same way in more modern versions of IE (at least 10 and 11). It does not fire when you navigate from (or refresh) the page before the onload event. For me the working solution was to bind the handler not only to onload, but also to onbeforeunload event.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons. One, like you said, the browser may not even be reaching the unload, so you should declare it above your body tag.

The other is that, as GoldenNewby already stated, you need to give the code some time to finish, such as an alert. This is because the JavaScript is cleared from memory the moment the next page is ready, and execution is simply stopped on the old script. If you can guarantee the script will take less time than a page load, you won't need an alert, but if it could take more than 2ms or so to execute, you will need to buy some time.

Answer (score 0):

IE has an `onbeforeunload` event, you can use that instead. Just set a flag so that your `onunload` can exit early if `onbeforeunload` already did its thing.

```
window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (window.isAlreadyUnloaded) return;
    window.isAlreadyUnloaded = true;
    // do your stuff here.
}
```